# How to split string letter separately and print in each label

Tags: ios, swift, split, uitextfield

I have the string like `"123456"`. And I have 6 labels. I need to split each number and I have to print in to each label.

Like my labels are:

```
Lab1 Lab2 Lab3 Lab4 Lab5 Lab6    ====  In screen design
```

My output have to:

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6
```

How can I split that each number and how I will display in my each label..I can also use 6 let or var to save each value and I can display it. But I don't know the functionality to b done.

Answer (score 1):

Given `text`

```
let text = "123456"
```

You need to transform it into an `Array` of `String(s)`.

```
let list = text.characters.map { String($0) }
```

Now you can check the array has at least 6 elements and assign each element to the `text` property of each label

```
if list.count > 5 {
    lab1.text = list[0]
    lab2.text = list[1]
    lab3.text = list[2]
    lab4.text = list[3]
    lab5.text = list[4]
    lab6.text = list[5]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple ForIn Loop :

```
 @IBOutlet weak var lbl1: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var lbl2: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var lbl3: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var lbl4: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var lbl5: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var lbl6: UILabel!

 let word = "123456"

    func splitWord(){
    // Swift 3.1
        for (i,char) in word.characters.enumerated(){
            switch i {
            case 0:
                lbl1.text = "\(char)"
            case 1:
                lbl2.text = "\(char)"
            case 2:
                lbl3.text = "\(char)"
            case 3:
                lbl4.text = "\(char)"
            case 4:
                lbl5.text = "\(char)"
            case 5:
                lbl6.text = "\(char)"
            default:
                print("Out of bound")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This would only set the text for `lbl1`.